# While adding record in AdvanceDataGrid: TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

I have an editable AdvancedDataGrid in flex:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dgTrans" dataProvider="{arrDtlTransDP}" styleName="advancedDataGrid" left="5" right="50"
    doubleClickEnabled="true" itemDoubleClick="fn_EditFieldDetail(event);" maxWidth="850"
    editable="true" top="27" rowHeight="20" verticalAlign="middle" resizableColumns="true"  
    allowMultipleSelection="true" allowDragSelection="true"
    horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" height="460">
<mx:columns>
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="S No." dataField="rrd_Trans_No" labelFunction="fn_GetSNo" width="100" editable="false"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Monthly Amount" dataField="rrd_Amount" width="110" labelFunction="fn_FormatAmountGrid"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Effective From" dataField="rrd_Effective_From" width="100" rendererIsEditor="true"
        labelFunction="fn_FormateDate" itemRenderer="mx.controls.DateField" editorDataField="selectedDate"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Narration" dataField="rrd_Narration" width="150" editable="true"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Rental Income a/c" dataField="rrd_Acc_Code" id="rrd_Acc_Code" width="120" labelFunction="fn_FormatCOAGrid"/>
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Description" dataField="rrd_Acc_Desc" id="rrd_Acc_Des" width="120" editable="false"/>
```

I have added following dummy data in case of new

```
var dgArray:Array = [{
    rrd_Trans_No:'1', rrd_Amount:'0.00',
    rrd_Effective_From: new Date(2016,0,1),
    rrd_Narration:'abc', rrd_Acc_Code:'0001',
    rrd_Acc_Desc:'acd'
}];

arrDtlTransDP.addItem(dgArray);
```

When I click on any column to edit this dummy data I face an error.

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties

Comment: This is Advance Data Grid:

Comment: What's the result of `trace(arrDtlTransDP);` if you add that at the top of your code?

Comment: Have you properly declared "arrDtlTransDP" variable somewhere in the code we can't see before you access its .additem() method? like `var arrDtlTransDP:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();`

Comment: If you get an error when you double click on the item you might want to post your fn_EditFieldDetail() method as well

Answer (score 0):

First, you're filling the arrDtlTransDP with an array. Add the item immediately to the arrDtlTransDP, skip the dgArray.

Like so:

```
arrDtlTransDP = new ArrayCollection();
arrDtlTransDP.addItem({
    rrd_Trans_No:'1', rrd_Amount:'0.00', 
    rrd_Effective_From: new Date(2016,0,1), 
    rrd_Narration:'abc', rrd_Acc_Code:'0001', 
    rrd_Acc_Desc:'acd'});
```

Second, we need more info on the implementations on the functions to properly tell you what could be the issue.

I've added these implementations and it worked without error with my above change:

```
    protected function fn_FormatAmountGrid(item:Object, column:AdvancedDataGridColumn):String {
        return item.rrd_Amount;
    }

    protected function fn_FormatCOAGrid(item:Object, column:AdvancedDataGridColumn):String {
        return item.rrd_Acc_Code;
    }

    protected function fn_FormateDate(item:Object, column:AdvancedDataGridColumn):String {
        return item.rrd_Effective_From;
    }

    protected function fn_GetSNo(item:Object, column:AdvancedDataGridColumn):String {
        return item.rrd_Trans_No;
    }

    protected function fn_EditFieldDetail(event:ListEvent):void {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

I hope this helps.